# Font-Awesome Circle with a Number and Shadow

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How can I use [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) to create a circle with a number in it that has a border and a **shadow**?  The typical answer I've found for a circle with a number and a border produces an square shadow not a circle shadow (at least the way I'm trying to do it).

I found a solution for creating a circle with a shadow but it is not working for #'s.  It is producing an oval, not a circle.

[image]

```css
#blah {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.46);
}

.icon-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.page-number-core {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.46);
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fix-editor {
  display: none;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="font-awesome@*" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='bold'>Incorrect shadow</div>
  </br>
  <div>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
        <i id='blah' class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <strong class="fa-stack-1x">1</strong>
      </span>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class='bold'>Produces an Oval - Not a Circle</div>
  </br>
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <i class="fa page-number-core page-number-dark">
            <span class="page-number-text page-number-text-light">1</span>
        </i>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class='bold'>Produces an Circle with Shadow but not for a #</div>
  </br>
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-comment page-number-core page-number-dark">
            <span class="page-number-text page-number-text-light fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
        </i>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div>
    <a href="http://codepen.io/Onomicon/pen/iDfld">Source of Circle with Shadow</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it imperative you use fontAwesome?

Comment: you need to set a static width and height in order to make a square to start with. then use border-radius, text-align and line-height to make a circle and center the font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to fulfill the exact requirements of the question I slightly modified the answer from @Michael Arrison to make it work with Font-Awesome.

The point is that the Font-Awesome CSS-class `fa-3x` uses `em` for setting the size:

```
.fa-3x {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

Hence the `height` and of `width` the `.circle` class should also be specified in `em` to make the whole thing work with different font sizes.

And because the circle of the Font-Awesome CSS-class `fa-circle-o` does not use 100% of the available height and width, the size of the `.circle` class is `5.1em` instead of `6em`.

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5.1em;
  height: 5.1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.46);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.46);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.46);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <strong class="fa-stack-1x">1</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

**Hint:**

When using `fa-lg` instead of `fa-3x` for the stack, the correct size for the `.circle` class is 2.2em.

Answer (score 4):

GCyrillus has it correct.  To make the container a circle, a fixed width and height are necessary.  Since you are just looking for a number, fontawesome has nothing to do with this.  Here's a flexbox example:

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.46);
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Font-Awesome version 5 someone can use below code :

```
<div class="circle">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <strong class="fa-stack-1x">1</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @sanjay - that suffers from #1 as described in the question.  See this [JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/spottedmahn/pmgbz8cy/)